# Freemarker - generate xml from flt template and java methods

Tags: java, xml, templates, freemarker

I am fairly new to Freemarker and to template engine in general.
Basicly I want to be able to generate two XML files (from two different templates) using java methods to feed data to the template.

For example:

- myTemplate1.ftl contain an opening and closing "res" tag with `getRes()` method as value (return 1 for exemple)
- myTemplate2.ftl contain an opening and closing "result" tag and takes `getResult()` method as value (return 2 for exemple)

How can I write one class `Main` to process this without being specific (I do not want to write line per line, because then it would be pointless to create an engine)

Can you please help me understand how it work through an example if possible ?

Regards

**EDIT with all the new informations :**

@fustaki This is very frustrating. It seems I need to go step by step to understand what I'm doing. So... Here is a very dumb example of where I am :

template1.ftl

```
<Email>${item.getEmail()}</Email><Language>${item.getLanguage()}</Language>
```

FillMyTemplate1.java

```
public String getEmail(){ return "test@test.com" }
public String getLanguage(){ return "EN" }
```

I am using a property file in order to use introspection : prop.properties which contain : 
    template1=fr.freemarker.test.xml.FillMyTemplate1

MainTest.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 Properties prop = new Properties();
 InputStream input = new FileInputStream("prop.properties");
 prop.load(input);
 Class<?> classe = Class.forName(prop.getProperty(args[0])); //where args[0] is "template1"

 Configuration config=new Configuration();
 config.setClassForTemplateLoading(MainTest.class, "templates");
 config.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
 Template template=config.getTemplate(args[0]+".ftl");

 Map<String, Object> dataModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 Writer consoleWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
 dataModel.put("item", classe.newInstance());
 template.process(dataModel, consoleWriter);
```

}

And the result : `<Email>test@test.com</Email><Language>EN</Language>`

In order to understand what you said, I need to know how a "data-provider" would look like in my case ? How can I get ride of this "item" in my map ? I understand the principle but not the technical solution...

Comment: How about http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_quickstart_all.html

Comment: I think you should give an example to that we can see what your usecase is.

Comment: Sure, let say I use two templates (it doesnt matter what they do, they just produce xml file), I define for each one a class (with some methods) that will be used in the corresponding data model.
What I want is to create one test class with a main method that will be able to produce one or the other xml file without changing the code. (I mean if just change the getTemplate() method to "template1" or "template2" and everything work...
Is it possible ?

Comment: So, assuming you aren't really a developer, I guess you just want to decide based on some runtime condition if which template will be invoked. In that case, in Java you can write things like `cfg.getTemplate(someCondition ? "template1.ftl" : "template2.ftl")`. Nothing FreeMarker specific there.

Comment: **EDIT** :
What I was looking for is called introspection (i didnt know...)
This leads me to another issue :
here is an exemple of what i am doing :
`Map<String, Object> tree = new HashMap<String, Object>();`
`tree.put("creationTime", classe.newInstance());`
Where `classe.newInstance()` is a key value taken from a property file, and "creationTime" is my variable in the corresponding ftl template : somthing like this : `${creationTime}`
I do not want to use the variable name here, I want to be generic, what is the logic to avoid it ?
I apologize for my poor level...

Answer (score 0):

Your `Main` process is in charge of producing the data (`List`, `Map` or other structured object) and templates will *use* the data to render your XMLs.
The tags used in the templates are independent from the data inside them.

Example where data are stored in a `List` that can be retrieved with a `getItems()` or in general is accessible from the freemarker engine.

```
<?xml>
<res>
    <#list items as item >
        <item>${item}</item>
    </#list>
</res>
```

You can create as much templates (*views*) as you want using the same `List items`.

I hope this clarify your troubles.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.
it allow me to explain myself more clearly. I do not want the `Main` process to produce the data. 

I want it to take any of my templates and also take the corresponding class that knows how to populate the chosen template with the corresponding data.

Do you see my point ? I am sorry I am not familiar with the correct terms.

Comment: OK, now I understand, and with that `classe.newInstance()` you want to put a _data producer_ in the map for the template, it sounds a bit weird. Why shouldnt the `Main` process detect the case, create a new instance of the data-producer class, call the methods to generate the data and put the data in the map? In this way you keep _controller-business_ layer separated from _view_, which is merely a data reading.

Comment: In same case you cannot retrieve all the data at once, imagine a very big xml in which data are generated on the fly by partial queries. In this case view and business aren't completely separated and you have to provide the template with a way to call the data-producer, as you are trying to do.

Comment: This make sense... I agree with your point of view. Can you explain what I should look to archive this if it is not too much to ask ? (just the basics for each steps)

Comment: It is a producer-consumer problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). The template reads the data in a standard way      
`<?xml><items><#list collection as document><item>${document}</item></#list></items>` where `collection` is a `class` implementing `Collection` (required by freemarker) but with the ability of handling the buffer of items and asking for new ones when it runs out.

Answer (score 0):

here is good example of freemarker. this application generate spring mvc crud operation 
using a freemarker template. 
[springmvcfreemarker](https://github.com/shakyasunil/springmvcfreemarker/blob/master/template/module-template.ftl)